# Script runs manually but not from cron

Tags: cron

As per the monitoring of my mysql replication status. I wrote a simple shell script with the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
date > /tmp/mysql_repl_status.txt
cd /usr/bin/
"/usr/bin/mysql" "-e" "SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G" >> /tmp/mysql_repl_status.txt
mail -s "Netspective MySQL replication status" name@abc.com < /tmp/mysql_repl_status.txt
```

The issue is when i execute this script manually it works fine, but using cron the script not works.

Using cron got the mail with the output of date command only. What is wrong with my side?

Comment: what is the entry in the crontab?

Comment: Does your `mysql` settings  need some password or user ?

Comment: In serverfault there is a generic answer to this issue....is there one in this SE for this problem?

Comment: @mdpc There's a summary in the tag wiki. I can find one answer that mentions shell, environment and percent: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47941/whats-wrong-with-these-two-cron-jobs/48005#48005

Answer (score 4):

Several possibilities:

1. Cron doesn't pass a full user environment to scripts run under cron.  So vars like $PATH can be different running under cron than running in a user terminal.
2. Cron requires a newline at the end of every line, so always keep a blank line at the end of the crontab file.

---

Maybe specify the full paths in the script, and see if that works to start with.

```
#!/bin/bash
statfile=/tmp/mysql_repl_status.txt
/bin/date > $statfile
cd /usr/bin
/usr/bin/mysql -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G" >> $statfile
/bin/mail -s "Netspective MySQL Replication Status" name@abc.com < $statfile
```

Comment: Quoting the path to a command (point 3) is *not* an issue. It's how you run a command with spaces or other special characters (which should never happen in a sensible system, but you know).

Comment: I would also add `2>&1` to the end of the mysql command line to pick up any error messages.

Comment: @DougO'Neal It would be better to configure mail properly so that cron's email doesn't get lost. If a cron job emits anything on stdout or stderr, cron sends the output in an email.

Comment: The script is executed under bash, not under a “reduced shell”. And anyway `cd /usr/bin` is supported by all shells.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant to say a reduced environment.  Cron often doesn't run script with the same environment a user would get in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 2):

Cron jobs are run with very little context. If you have a `.my.cnf` file in your home directory, that could contain the authentication details needed for the `mysql` command to work. You probably also need the full path to `mail` - see what `which mail` prints.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing full path for every command, it would be helpful to set `PATH` variable in the script file itself

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
date > /tmp/mysql_repl_status.txt
cd /usr/bin/
"/usr/bin/mysql" "-e" "SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G" >> /tmp/mysql_repl_status.txt
mail -s "Netspective MySQL replication status" name@abc.com < 
/tmp/mysql_repl_status.txt`
```

Answer (score 0):

use `bash -l -c`

eg:

```
* * * * * bash -l -c '/dsds/fddfd/something.sh' > /tmp/something.log
```